# UiScrollview scroll paging

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have implemented an UIScrollView.It contains small images of 60 width size.
The scroll movement always steps 3 pictures forward or back, not one by one as I need. Please see the attached pictures that explain this point.

[image]

ScrollView has paging enabled. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[fotosJugadores objectAtIndex:i]];
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * myImage.size.width + 120;
        UIImageView *awesomeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height)];
        awesomeView.image = myImage;
        awesomeView.tag = i;
        [self.jugadorSlide addSubview:awesomeView];
        awesomeView=nil;
    }

    [jugadorSlide setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    jugadorSlide.contentSize = CGSizeMake(65 * numberOfViews+240,78);
    jugadorSlide.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
    jugadorSlide.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [jugadorSlide setContentOffset:CGPointMake(((65 * numberOfViews)/2), 0)];
    [self scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:jugadorSlide];
```

Many thanks

Comment: I don't really understand "steps 3 pictures forward or back" could you add some screenshots ? Also, I don't see the paging enabled in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what you mean. Would these links help you

[UIScrollView - with paging enabled, can I "change" the page width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256081/uiscrollview-with-paging-enabled-can-i-change-the-page-width)

[Paging UIScrollView with different page widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089510/paging-uiscrollview-with-different-page-widths)

[UIScrollView + pagingEnabled, scroll half a page?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=634462)

Hope this helps